# how to combine query results of several times function call with entity framework5?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-5

i want to use a function to query db with linq and combine their results,i write the code as follows but cannot work , any one can help me? thanks!

the error:(The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed)

the part code:

```
public static IEnumerable<UserLocation> loadedUserList;

public static IEnumerable<UserLocation> combinedUserList;


public static void loadDataInStaticClass()
            {
                using (var context = new SptialTestEntities())
                {
                    var loadedUserList = from newRcords in context.UserLocations
                                         where newRcords.ID > lastLoadedID
                                         select newRcords;

                    if (loadedUserList.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var user in loadedUserList)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(user.UserName);

                        }
                        if (combinedUserList != null)
                        {
                            combinedUserList = loadedUserList.Union(combinedUserList);
                            foreach (var cc in combinedUserList)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("\n after combined：" + cc.UserName);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            combinedUserList = loadedUserList;
                            Console.WriteLine("\nfirst run ：" + combinedUserList.Count());
                            foreach (var cc in combinedUserList)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("\n user:" + cc.UserName);
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }


            }
```

the problem is: the first call is ok, but the second report error: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed ,and how? 
thanks!

Comment: I tested your code in Linqpad creating an explicit DataContext, and it worked with no errors... Did you find out the issue? Where exactly does the error happen, on the first foreach?

Comment: Wasp Thank you reply and i try again and get the same error.my enviroment is :ef5 ,visual studio 2012,and the entity has a mapped colum whose type is a GEOGRAPHY, as you described above , do you use datacontext or dbcontext? is it a point ?

Comment: and if i remove using syntax , the code can work and i don't konw if i remove the using {} sentence, has it any potienal mistake after many times call the function to load data.

Comment: i call the function from program class and i put the function in a static class,and call it with static class name.function name,is it a mistake?

Comment: after debug i set a breakpoint at the if (combinedUserList != null) line and i found the second time when i call the function , the function can get the data secondly and when use the data's property such as combinedUserList.Count(), the exception occured and report the error : the dbcontext has been disposed.

Comment: the exactly point is the second function call  , and  run to foreach (var cc in combinedUserList) the exception throws. or i add a line under if (loadedUserList.Any()){ Console.Writeline(combinedUserList.Count());the exception throws.

Answer (score 0):

i paste the whole code and some one can run and check the mistake and thank u:
userLocation a table contain userid,username,userlocation(geography type) ,and 
i user database first mode in visual studio 2012 and map the userLocation to a entity   of SptialTestEntities.

```
Program.cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{

  for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("\nrun{0}times, i);
      Test.LoadUsersFromDB();
   }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Spatial;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;

namespace SptialMatch
{
    class Test
    {
        public static int lastedLoadedRecordID = 14;

        public static IEnumerable<UserLocation> loadedUserList;
        public static IEnumerable<UserLocation> combinedUserList;

        public static void LoadUsersFromDB()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n------------------------load data begin----------------------------------------------------------");

                //var context = new SptialTestEntities();
                using (var context = new SptialTestEntities())
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch loadStopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
                    loadStopwatch.Start();

                    loadedUserList = from newRcords in context.UserLocations
                                      where newRcords.ID > lastedLoadedRecordID
                                      select  newRcords;
                   if (loadedUserList.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var loadUser in loadedUserList)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\n loaded element：" + loadUser.UserName);
                        }
                        if (combinedUserList != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\nnot first run：" );
                            foreach (var cc in combinedUserList)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("\n before union：" + cc.UserName);
                            }


                            IEnumerable<UserLocation> tmp = loadedUserList.AsEnumerable();
                            combinedUserList = tmp.Union<UserLocation>(combinedUserList.AsEnumerable(), new UserComparer2()).ToList();

                            Console.WriteLine("\nnot first run after union：" );
                            foreach (var cc in combinedUserList)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("\n after union the user name is：" + cc.UserName);
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            combinedUserList = loadedUserList;
                            Console.WriteLine("\nfirst run the count is：" + combinedUserList.Count());
                            foreach (var cc in combinedUserList)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("\n the combined list：" + cc.UserName);
                            }
                        }

                        var maxID = loadedUserList.Max(myMaxID => myMaxID.ID);

                        lastedLoadedRecordID = lastedLoadedRecordID + 1;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n no new data！");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n-----------------load end，no new data yet------------------------------------------------");

                        Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    }
                    loadStopwatch.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("\nload time cost{0} seconds。", loadStopwatch.Elapsed);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n---------------------load end ----------------------------------------------------------");

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n exception message：" + ex.Message);

            }




        }

    }


    class UserComparer2 : IEqualityComparer<UserLocation>
    {
        public bool Equals(UserLocation x, UserLocation y)
        {

            //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

            //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                return false;

            //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
            return x.ID == y.ID && x.UserName == y.UserName;
        }

        // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
        // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

        public int GetHashCode(UserLocation user)
        {
            //Check whether the object is null
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(user, null)) return 0;

            //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
            int hashUserName = user.UserName == null ? 0 : user.UserName.GetHashCode();

            //Get hash code for the Code field.
            int hashUserCode = user.ID.GetHashCode();

            //Calculate the hash code for the product.
            return hashUserName ^ hashUserCode;
        }

    }
}
```